# Print a field of a list of protobuf messages in java

Tags: java, loops, lambda, protobuf-java

I have a protobuf message `foo` with some fields including `id` field which is uint32.

```
message foo {
uint32 foo_id = 1;
bool committed = 2;
...
}
```

In my main class and main function, I have a list of foos: `List<foo> foos`. I want to printout the  `foo_id`s of all foos in line. I know there is straight forward for loop option as follows but was wondering if there is any clean lambda way of doing it.

I tried

```
String s = "The list of ids are: "
for(i = 0; i < foos.size(); i++) {
   s = s + Integer.toString(foos.get(i).getFooId());
}
System.out.println(s);
```

but I'm expecting a better and cleaner way.

Comment: Why is a "lambda" way "cleaner"? You can write something like `foos.foreach( foo -> s+= f.getFooId())` though.

Comment: But note: you probably want spaces between the different numbers. Also note: this might turn ugly quickly, depending on the number of entries in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use lambda (or like python way), you must know the `stream()` apis (possibly and the google's guava lib).

```java
// guava 
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

System.out.println(Joiner.on(",").join(
    foos.stream().map(foo::getFooId).map(String::valueOf).iterator()
));
```